# Seasonal_Decompose gives plot filled to the brim with blue lines

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, statsmodels, decomposition

When i'm plotting the seasonal_decompose I get a plot filled to the brim with blue lines, the whole plot is filled. What is going wrong?[seasonal decompose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6tlT.jpg)

```
decomposition = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(df1['Column1'], period=12)


plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.subplot(4, 1, 1)
plt.plot(df1['Column1'], label='Original')
plt.legend()


plt.subplot(4, 1, 2)
plt.plot(decomposition.trend, label='Trend')
plt.legend()


plt.subplot(4, 1, 3)
plt.plot(decomposition.seasonal, label='Season')
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(4, 1, 4)
plt.plot(decomposition.resid, label='Residual')
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I've tried using different type of decompose ("Multiplicative" or "Additive")

Comment: Looks like there is an order problem with one of your vector, indeed this is impossible to tell without a [mcve].

Comment: To be reproducible, it also needs data, no screenshot copy paste and format or provide a link to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a MCVE for seasonal decomposition:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

df = pd.read_csv("https://gml.noaa.gov/webdata/ccgg/trends/co2/co2_trend_gl.csv", header=24)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(dict(year=df.year, month=df.month, day=df.day))
df = df.set_index("timestamp")

decomposition = seasonal_decompose(df["smoothed"], period=365)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 1, sharex=True)
df.smoothed.plot(ax=axes[0])
decomposition.trend.plot(ax=axes[1])
decomposition.seasonal.plot(ax=axes[2])
decomposition.resid.plot(ax=axes[3])
```

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to tell without a [mcve] which includes dataset as well as actual code. If you share it, i'll have a look.

Comment: Nice, don't hesitate to upvote and/or mark as solved if you think it deserve it.